# How to find number of perfect squares in the given range?

Tags: c, algorithm, math

It gives an error as terminated due to timeout for large input of `t`.
To find the number of perfect squares in the given range

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main() 
    {

        double s,e,i;
       int t;
       scanf("%d",&t);
       for (;t>0;t--)
            {
             int cnt=0;
             scanf("%lf%lf",&s,&e);
             for (i=s;i<=e;i++)
                {
                 if (sqrt(i)==ceil(sqrt(i)))
                 cnt++;
                }
            printf("%d\n",cnt);
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a trick.

- Find the square root of lower and upper bound
- take their integral part and then
- subtract the integral part of lower bound from upper bound.

You also need to check if lower bound is a perfect square or not. If it is then add `1` to the difference.

For example: Number of perfect squares between `1` and `100` is `10 - 1 = 9`. Since `1` is also a perfect square therefore add `1` and hence result will be `10`.

```
int result = (int)sqrt(upper_bound) - (int)sqrt(lower_bound);  
if(lower_bound == (int)sqrt(lower_bound)*(int)sqrt(lower_bound))  
    result += 1;
```

Note that I considered upper and lower bound inclusive.

Comment: +1.  This is the right approach.  "check the lower bound", "check the upper bound", and "add 1" all fall into the category of "are the bounds inclusive".

Answer (score 4):

Method 2 (Efficient) We can simply take square root of a and square root of b and to count the perfect squares between them using

```
floor(sqrt(b)) - ceil(sqrt(a)) + 1
```

We take floor of sqrt(b) because we need to consider
numbers before b

We take ceil of sqrt(a) because we need to consider
numbers after a

For example, let b = 24, a = 8.  floor(sqrt(b)) = 4
ceil(sqrt(a)) = 3 And number of squares is 4 - 3 + 1 = 2 The two numbers are 9 and 16

Comment: good explanation and code reduction than the original answer